# CORS request header parameters not sending in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, http-headers, cors, cross-domain, swagger

I try to use swagger ui for rest api documentation. Rest API created with WCF service. I solved cors issue, service accepts OPTIONS method. But request has a header parameter which name is SessionUUID, this parameter doesn't send to service. When i debug the service side, this parameter does not come. This problem is only in Chrome. **Chrome blocks to header params in cors request.**

Cors problem's solving on WCF Service like this;

1. I added new behavior and header params are defined

   ```
   public class EnableCorsEndpointBehavior : BehaviorExtensionElement, IEndpointBehavior
   {
      ...

       public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
       {
           var requiredHeaders = new Dictionary<string, string>();

           requiredHeaders.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
           requiredHeaders.Add("Access-Control-Request-Method", "POST,GET,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS");
           requiredHeaders.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Accept-Language, SessionUUID, Origin, X-Custom-Header, sessionuuid");
           requiredHeaders.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
           endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new ServiceInspector(requiredHeaders));
       }    
      ...
     }
   ```

   2. I added response headers in inspector. Header parameter which named as SessionUUID is checked in AfterReceiveRequest but it is **null**, because of this problem.

      ```
      public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel, System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext instanceContext)
      {
          try
          {


              WebHeaderCollection headers = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers;
              string requestTo = request.Headers.To.ToString();


              if (!requestTo.Contains("login") && request.GetType().Name != "InternalByteStreamMessage")
              {
                  if (headers["SessionUUID"] == null)
                  {
                      throw new RestAppException("401", "Oturum bilgisi bulunamadı.");
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      DateTime requestDate = DateTime.Now;
                      string sessionUUID = headers["SessionUUID"] != null ? headers["SessionUUID"].AsString() : headers["sessionuuid"].AsString();
                      sessionManager.CheckSessionByUUID(sessionUUID, requestDate);

                      sessionManager.UpdateExpireDate(sessionUUID, requestDate);
                      sessionManager.SetSessionByUUID(sessionUUID);
                  }
              }
          }
          catch (RestAppException ex)
          {
              ex.Message = "İşlem Başarısız";
              throw ex;
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
              throw ex;
          }

          return null;
      }

      public void BeforeSendReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState)
      {
          var httpHeader = reply.Properties["httpResponse"] as HttpResponseMessageProperty;
          foreach (var item in requiredHeaders)
          {
              httpHeader.Headers.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
          }
      }
      ```

How can i solve this chrome issue?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add a Chrome extension to allow custom headers.

Here are some that you could use:

1. [WebRequestAPI](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest)
2. [Mod Header](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj)

In case you want to try out Mozilla Firefox, use its extension [modify-headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/modify-headers/).

Comment: Mod Header works thank you very much. But i need to solve this problem on the server side.

Comment: try adding this: requiredHeaders.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "SessionUUID");

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem . It may be related to the url.

My problem was solved when I entered with "www".

If already you entered with "www", delete this and try again.